# Azure Function not working for parameterized API

Tags: .net, azure

I followed a solution to my problem from this below thread

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62596741/azure-function-not-working-cannot-declare-namespace-in-script-code
```

I created a code locally and published it online - it was working on both - local & Azure function.

Below code snippet isworking on both - local & Azure function. **Notice that filename is hardcoded**.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            string filename = "success.png";
            string storageconnstring = "**********";
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageconnstring);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("demo");

            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);
            var blobUri = blobClient.Uri;
            BlobContainerClient targetContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("demo-copy");//This is the container where we want to copy the blob
            BlobClient targetBlobClient = targetContainerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);
            await targetBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(blobUri);


            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this code is working only locally - **the ONLY change I did was that now you can pass the filename.**
What I am doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string filename = req.Query["filename"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            filename = filename ?? data?.filename;

            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename)
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a file name in the query string or in the request body for initiating a temporary copy"
                : $"This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

            string storageconnstring = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mainices;AccountKey=lrlWVXi9tWDfkjv6XMcMgylPG2fU78nOcK3AwJkRJTBKDQ4FdxJkieYiGBhfFTYULl+IHey0OJASpkHlg25Eaw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(storageconnstring);

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("demo");

            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);
            var blobUri = blobClient.Uri;
            BlobContainerClient targetContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("demo-copy");//This is the container where we want to copy the blob
            BlobClient targetBlobClient = targetContainerClient.GetBlobClient(filename);
            await targetBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(blobUri);


            return new OkObjectResult(targetBlobClient.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What *does* happen when you run it remotely? What is the nature of "it doesn't work"?

Comment: When I ran locally i did this and it worked -> http://localhost:7071/api/Function1?filename=sample2.txt... Post publishing new code .. I did this .. got 401 ... -> https://copyfiles.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?filename=sample2.txt

Comment: do you know what a 401 error means? Does that suggest anything to you?

Comment: Unauthorized? do I need to make any changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you defined the autorization level as functions, it is expecting a function key:

```
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function
```

you'll need to add it to your querystring:

https://<APP_NAME>.azurewebsites.net/api/<FUNCTION_NAME>?code=<API_KEY>

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#obtaining-keys

PS: do not forget to pass the filename parameter too

Comment: Perfect!!!, Thank you Thiago Custodio.. You are awesome

Comment: @Thiago, what's changed? Why was the Key not previously necessary?

Comment: because it's generated / handled by Azure