# How to open a container file in browser Azure C# Function

Tags: .net, azure

I have copied a file 1.txt from Container A to Container B.

I am also returning the complete URL of the copied file.

```
    return new OkObjectResult(targetBlobClient.Uri);
```

Now, rather than returning I just want to open this file directly in the current browser tab which i used to invoke the function .
How can I go about that ?
Please guide.

Comment: So you simply want to open the file and display in the browser, correct? 2 Questions: 1) How are you invoking the function? and 2) What happens currently when you return `OkObjectResult(targetBlobClient.Uri);`?

Comment: 1)I am publishing the code from VS 2019 ..doing this ... https://copyfiles.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?filename=sample2.txt&code=*** 2) right now it just prints the URL of copied file.

Comment: So you simply want to open the file and display in the browser, correct?  - Yes, Please.

Comment: Typically you would want to consume your function through some code instead of directly invoking it in the browser. Can't you handle it in the client code? So you get the URL as response and then you can redirect to that URL in the client only.

Comment: if this were a Spring boot or java thing - I would have done it .. c# ..my exposure is hardly 15 hours .. I was hoping there was some inbuilt redirect functionality in c#.. I already have the URL .. just need to open it in browser .. sounds simple ..

Comment: In normal MVC, there's a redirect action result (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.redirectresult?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=aspnet-mvc-5.2). Please see if you can use that.

Comment: Gaurav !! .. it worked .. thank you !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that you’re unblocked .

Comment: one last help please .. and i will have a good weekend .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604825/generate-sas-token-c-sharp-programmatically

Comment: It’s actually pretty easy. I’ll try to answer soon (currently away from computer).

Answer (score 1):

Credits to Gaurav @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri-ais

```
  string responseURL= targetBlobClient.Uri.ToString();

  return new RedirectResult(responseURL, false);
```