# Generate SAS token c# programmatically

Tags: .net, azure

I have copied a file 1.txt from Container A to Container B.

I am also able to get the complete URL of the copied file and also able to open it in the same browser tab  as long as container is public.

Now I am making my container private .. I was hoping there was a simple API which could give me SAS URL & TOKEN on the spot .

Is there any such API ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
        Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder()
        {
            BlobContainerName = "demo-copy",
            BlobName = "test.txt",
            ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),//Let SAS token expire after 5 minutes.
        };
        blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Read);//User will only be able to read the blob and it's properties
        var sasToken = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)).ToString();
        var sasUrl = blobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri + "?" + sasToken;
```

Basically you need to make use of [`BlobSasBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.blobsasbuilder?view=azure-dotnet) class.

Comment: Thank you Gaurav .. You are an awesome rock-star!

Comment: <blush/> :). Glad to be of help!

Comment: Gaurav .. this SAS url is @ container level ..How can we have SAS  token @ file level inside container ?

Comment: Nope. This SAS token is for `test.txt` blob in `demo-copy` container.

Comment: if i have 2 files .. a.txt & b.txt .. with token from a.txt .. i am able to open b.txt ..

Comment: i went into portal .. there when manually generating SAS token .. i noticed they are unique for each file ..

Comment: you are right Gaurav .. i did a massive boo-boo .. i deleted line             BlobName = "test.txt",
.. my bad .. sorry bud .. learned something new today :)

Comment: Yes, if you don't include the `BlobName` parameter the SAS token will be generated for container and thus will be applicable to all blobs in that container.

Comment: understood .. please guide .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679573/merge-2-functions-azure

Comment: hi Gaurav .. please help .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783629/generate-azure-functions-access-code-on-the-fly-programmatically

Comment: Took me a while to figure out my SDK was out of date. This version or later supports all the features in this answer: <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.8.4" />

Comment: i tried above code and it has correction in this line :   var sasUrl = blobClient.BaseUri.AbsoluteUri + containerName + "/" + blobName +  "?" + sasToken;