# Merge 2 Functions | Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have one Azure Function Project in VS2019 - COPY
then one more named - DELETE.

I deployed both of those in the portal.

I noticed now I have 2 Functions App  with one function each.

Is there a way I can merge both of these functions under OPERATIONS Functions App ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should work with only one project (Visual Studio project). After a deployment, it will be a single function app with your functions on it. (Two functions, under the same function app)

Comment: you mean just copy the DELETE.cs at the same directory structure level of COPY.cs and deploy.. that's it ?

Comment: is this even feasible ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783629/generate-azure-functions-access-code-on-the-fly-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

I guess first you need to understand difference between function app and function. Everytime you create a new Azure function project in Visual Studio it's a Function app which creates a function class based on function type you selected eg. Http trigger etc.
Now in case if you want to add another function then can be part of your existing project just do a right click on project and add existing or new function class.