# Generate Azure Function's Access Code on the fly programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I have couple of Azure functions (written in c#) .. URL of which i have given to a different team to call\invoke .. I noticed that the access code which is suffixed is always the same hence poses a security risk ..

Is there a way where we can generate Azure Function's Access Code on the fly programmatically and append it to the function's URL .. so that each and every invocation would have a Uniquely  generated access code ?

Please guide.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it using azure cli / rest api  / powershell:

```
$keyName = "MyFunctionKey"
$payload = (@{ properties=@{ name=$keyName; value="abcd1234" } } `
    | ConvertTo-Json -Compress).Replace('"', '\"')
az rest --method put `
    --uri "$resourceId/functions/$functionName/keys/$($keyName)?api-version=2018-11-01" `
    --body "$payload"
```

source:

https://markheath.net/post/managing-azure-functions-keys-2

if you want, you can also achieve the same result using REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatefunctionsecret

Comment: i was hoping to integrate it with my .net function..

Comment: is there any .net API to renew and fetch new function key ?

Comment: if you search for the endpoint you probably will find the related rest API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/createorupdatefunctionsecret