# Unable to get Blob SAS URL using Azure Function Blob trigger

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-triggers, sas-token

I'm using a Blob trigger Azure function to get Blob files data whenever any file is uploaded to the Container.

```
 public static void Run(Stream myBlob,string BlobTrigger,System.Uri uri, string name, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes + URL: {uri}");
}
```

Using the above method, I'm able to get the URL of the Item uploaded.
Currently, the above code is generated using Develop in Portal option provided by Azure.

Is there a way I can get **SAS URL** of the Blob file that has been uploaded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from our end. Here is how I could able to achieve when blob is uploaded each time.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp10
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "ConnectionStore")]Stream myBlob, Uri uri, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
            BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = "<YOURCONTAINERNAME>",
                BlobName = name,
                ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5),
            };
            blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.All);
            string accountName = "<YOURACCOUNTNAME>";
            string accountKey = "<YOURACCOUNTKEY>";
            var sasToken = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey)).ToString();
            var sasUrl = uri.AbsoluteUri + "?" + sasToken;
            Console.WriteLine(sasUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

**RESULT :**

[image]

**In storage account**

[image]

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Generate SAS token c# programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604825/generate-sas-token-c-sharp-programmatically)