# How to get account name and account key from a connection string or a BlobServiceClient?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure Blob storage connection string in a config file, for example:

```
"Storage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xyz;AccountKey=abc==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

In the app, this is used to instanciate a BlobServiceClient, here is the registration happening in the Startup.cs:

```
  builder.Services.AddAzureClients(options => options.AddBlobServiceClient(configuration.GetValue<string>("Storage")));
```

This works and a BlobServiceClient can be injected in the constructor of a service and use it.

Now for a new scenario, I need to generate a Sas token. I want to use this solution [Generate SAS token c# programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62604825/generate-sas-token-c-sharp-programmatically) but it requires to create a new `StorageSharedKeyCredential` with the help of 2 parameters: `accountName` and `accountKey`.

### Question

Since these values are present in the connection string, I could parse it somehow to get them, but probably there is a smarter way to retrieve separate `accountName` and `accountKey` values from a connection string or from a `BlobServiceClient` instance?

Or can I get a `StorageSharedKeyCredential` in an other way than creating it manually from accountName/accountKey, for example from a connection string?

---

Update for Gaurav Mantri's answer

```
var blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
{
    BlobContainerName = "containerName",
    BlobName = "fileName",
    ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15),
};

blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobSasPermissions.Read | BlobSasPermissions.Write);
```

Comment: What kind of SAS token (account/container/blob) you want to create?

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri probably blob, I just want to create a specific file in an existing container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`BlobBaseClient.GenerateSasUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.generatesasuri?view=azure-dotnet) method. Essentially your code would be something like:

```
var blobClient = new BlobBaseClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);
var sasUri = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(/*blob SAS builder parameters*/);
```

Comment: 403 error happens when you use SAS token for an operation the permissions of which are not included in the token e.g try to upload blob with read permission in the token. I would recommend checking that. Otherwise, please ask a separate question with the code and I’ll take a look.