# What is an efficient way to copy a subset of files from one container to another?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have millions of files in one container and I need to copy ~100k to another container in the same storage account. What is the most efficient way to do this?

I have tried:

1. Python API -- Using BlobServiceClient and related classes, I make a BlobClient for the source and destination and start a copy with `new_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url)`. This runs at roughly 7 files per second.
2. azcopy (one file per line) -- Basically a batch script with a line like `azcopy copy <source w/ SAS> <destination w/ SAS>` for every file. This runs at roughly 0.5 files per second due to azcopy's overhead.
3. azcopy (1000 files per line) -- Another batch script like the above, except I use the `--include-path` argument to specify a bunch of semicolon-separated files at once. (The number is arbitrary but I chose 1000 because I was concerned about overloading the command. Even 1000 files makes a command with 84k characters.) Extra caveat here: I cannot rename the files with this method, which is required for about 25% due to character constraints on the system that will download from the destination container. This runs at roughly 3.5 files per second.

Surely there must be a better way to do this, probably with another Azure tool that I haven't tried. Or maybe by tagging the files I want to copy then copying the files with that tag, but I couldn't find the arguments to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Please check with below references:

**1.** [**AZCOPY**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-synchronize) would be best for best performance for copying blobs within
same storage or other storage accounts .we can force a synchronous
copy by specifying "/SyncCopy" parameter for AZCopy to ensures that
the copy operation will get consistent speed. [azcopy sync |
Microsoft Docs .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-sync?msclkid=32f41f57c1ac11ecb7a5e31ede5c647c)

> But note that AzCopy performs the synchronous copy by
> downloading the blobs to local memory and then uploads to the Blob
> storage destination. So performance will also depend on network
> conditions between the location where AZCopy is being run and Azure
> DC location. Also note that /**SyncCopy** might generate **additional
> egress cost** comparing to asynchronous copy, the recommended approach
> is to use this sync option with azcopy in the Azure VM which is in the same region as
> your source storage account to avoid egress cost.
> [**Choose a tool and strategy to copy blobs - Learn | Microsoft Docs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/copy-blobs-from-command-line-and-code/2-choosing-a-tool-and-strategy)

**2.** `StartCopyAsync` is one of the ways you can try for copy within a
storage account .

References:
1.  [.net - Copying file across Azure container without using azcopy - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586809/copying-file-across-azure-container-without-using-azcopy?msclkid=9dff355cc1a411eca846f479932cab1b)
2.   [Copying Azure Blobs Between Containers the Quick Way (markheath.net)](https://markheath.net/post/azure-blob-copy-quick?msclkid=c6068e02c19f11ec9789368d4994e85b)

**3.** You may consider `Azure data factory` in case of millions of files
but also note that it may be expensive and little timeouts may occur
but it may be worth for repeated kind of work.

References:
1.   [Copy millions of files (andrewconnell.com)](https://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/azure-data-factory-file-copy-based-on-contents/?msclkid=494f40f4c1a511ecbb24654831929f3a) ,  [GitHub(microsoft docs)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage.md?msclkid=b897c75ac1a211ecaaa502d48c35a1cf)
2.  [File Transfer between container to another container - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/318680/file-transfer-between-container-to-another-contain.html?msclkid=9dff0ad2c1a411ec95b5bce13fd2ab0d)

**4.** Also check out and try the `Azure storage explorer` [copy blob container to
another](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-explorer-blobs#copy-a-blob-container)